# How do I get the Access Token via the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService in the Client Credentials Flow?

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I have created a client with Spring Security. As Authorization Server I use Keycloak.
Now I want to gain access to the access token, using the parameter annotation `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient(registrationId = "keycloak")`
I get access to the token, but when I go through the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` I only get back NULL, and I don't understand why.

Here is my implementation:

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=test-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=b466bd4e-8dec-4af2-b90a-ab3fc06009b6
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/master
```

SecurityConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.oauth2Client();
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("client")
public class ExampleRestController
{
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

    @GetMapping("resource")
    public void runSecure(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient(registrationId = "keycloak") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client)
    {
        var serviceClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient("keycloak", "anonymousUser");
        System.out.println(serviceClient.getAccessToken()); // NULL

        System.out.println((client.getAccessToken())); // NOT NULL
    }
}
```

Hope for help, thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Here is my solution to get a flexible access to the access-token using a service:

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=test-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=b466bd4e-8dec-4af2-b90a-ab3fc06009b6
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Client registration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientRegistrationConfiguration
{
    private static final String KEYCLOAK = "keycloak";

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistration clientRegistration(OAuth2ClientProperties properties)
    {
        return withRegistrationId(KEYCLOAK)
                .tokenUri(properties.getProvider().get(KEYCLOAK).getTokenUri())
                .clientId(properties.getRegistration().get(KEYCLOAK).getClientId())
                .clientSecret(properties.getRegistration().get(KEYCLOAK).getClientSecret())
                .authorizationGrantType(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(ClientRegistration clientRegistration)
    {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository)
    {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService)
    {
        var authorizedClientProvider = builder().clientCredentials().build();
        var authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

My custom token service:

```
@Service
public class DefaultTokenService implements TokenService
{
    @Autowired
    private AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager clientManager;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken getOAuth2AccessToken()
    {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(clientManager.authorize(withClientRegistrationId("keycloak").principal("Keycloak").build())).getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autowire OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager bean and explicitly send a token request:

```
authorizedClientManager.authorize(request)
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html

Comment: Is there any way to use Spring Security's auto-configuration here?
So that the request does not have to be assembled and the implementation works similar to the parameter annotation @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient ?

Comment: This seems more than dependency injection, configuration or instance building. This is an action that needs to take place inside a controller/service at a specific point in the application logic. It also needs to handle errors in an app specific way.

Comment: Okay thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting infor in application.yml
[image]

Config Sercurity
[image]

Get access token
[image]

Comment: Yes, that works too. The disadvantage is that you need the controller method as an entry point. Which is not practical for an HTTP interceptor, for example.